# rewire rule for custom taxonomy of custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

So I have spent almost a week trying to solve this problem,
I have a custom post type called `Product` with a custom taxonomy called `Category`.
What I want is be able to list all products in a category when I got to a url similar to `acme.com/products/category/cctv`, in this case I want it to display all products inside the category `cctv` but it is redirecting me to a 404 page. I have verified that ?product_category=cctv works, that is how I reached on the conclusion that the problem lies within the rewrite rule.

Here is my code,

 **Products Custom post type**

```
    $args = array(
            'labels'=>array(
                    'name' => 'Products',
                    'singular_name' => 'Product',
                    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Product',
                    'edit_item' => 'Edit Item',
                    'new_item'  => 'Add New Product',
                    'view_item' => 'View Product',
                    'search_items' => 'Search Products',
                    'not_found'    =>'No Products found',
                    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Products found in trash'
            ),
            'taxonomies'   => array( 'product_category'),
            'query_var' => 'products',
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products', 'with_front' => true, 'pages' => true, 'feeds' => true,),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'public'  => true,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/images/products.png',
            'supports' => array(
                    'title',
                    'thumbnail',
                    'editor'
                ),
        );
register_post_type('tg_product',$args);
```

**Category Custom Taxonomy**

```
$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Categories', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'alle360' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Category', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'alle360' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Categories', 'alle360' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Categories', 'alle360' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Category', 'alle360' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Category:', 'alle360' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Category Name', 'alle360' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Category', 'alle360' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Category', 'alle360' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Category', 'alle360' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate categories with commas', 'alle360' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Categories', 'alle360' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove categories', 'alle360' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used categories', 'alle360' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'alle360' ),
);
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                       => 'products/category',
    'with_front'                 => true,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'query_var'                  => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'rewrite'                    => $rewrite
);
```

so there you have it. Please someone shed a light on why this is not working.

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken to determine the cause of the problem? Are any errors being logged? Generally you should try and reduce your code to a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with details of any errors or incorrect output.

Comment: I have verified that `?product_category=cctv` works, that is how I reached on the conclusion that the problem lies within the rewrite rule.

Comment: Please edit that information into your question. I don't have the expertise required to answer your question but this sort of information may be essential for potential answerers.

Comment: Can I assume you flushed the rewrite rules?

Comment: @bobdye yep... did that so many times.

Answer (score 0):

```
register_taxonomy( 'products', 'category', $args ); and Change
$rewrite = array(
'slug'                       => 'category',
'with_front'                 => true,
'hierarchical'               => true,
);
```

Comment: I want the url to be `acme.com/products/category/cctv` , what you suggested only works for  `acme.com/category/cctv`, and on your `register_taxonomy` you have interchanged taxonomy name with custom post name.